# How to set validation of marker's color in android (Google Map API)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I want to set validation base on marker's color.

First, this is my code of marker's looping, so it will show markers (This is not the main problem, this code works)

```
for(int i = 0; i < datMarkerList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i < 50) {
            DAT_MARKER datMarker = datMarkerList.get(i);
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(datMarker.getLATITUDE(), datMarker.getLONGITUDE()))
                    .title(datMarker.getDESCRIPTION())
                    .snippet(datMarker.getID_MARKER() + ""));
            markers.add(marker);
        } else {
            continue;
        }

        DAT_MARKER_OP datMarkerOp = datMarkerOpList.get(i);
        if(datMarkerOp.getKODE_PAJAK() == 0) { //KODE PAJAK HOTEL
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }else if(datMarkerOp.getKODE_PAJAK() == 1) { //KODE PAJAK RESTAURANT
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
        }else { //KODE PAJAK HOTEL DAN RESTAURANT
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        }
    }
```

Then, from those icon, I want to make validation base on those colors, so I think I will set it here (also I put the algorithms) :

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    linCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //mapSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    linCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //IF marker's color is RED
                //Statement
            //IF marker's color is YELLOW
                //Statement
            //IF marker's color is BLUE
                //Statement

        }
    });
```

That's it. I've been thinking and I have no idea about the code, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mix your app logic with colors.
You want to do some action based on marker type, not it's color. Colors can be changed.
So, you need to link you additional info to markers, for example through the Map.

```
Map<Marker,DAT_MARKER_OP> markersMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And in your marker's looping:

```
markersMap.put(marker, datMarkerOp);
```

After this you can get your DAT_MARKER_OP in onClick

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    linCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    linCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DAT_MARKER_OP datMarkerOp = markersMap.get(marker);
            if(datMarkerOp.getKODE_PAJAK() == 0) {
                // your logic
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So, maybe there is no validation for icon, while there is validation for title, snippet etc. But this is the best solution, thank you, mate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use title of the marker to identify it or you can use Hashmap to save maker and its corresponding info in it as did it here
http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Comment: @pengrad but how to get the value of marker from markersMap?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 identifiers here.. Title and snippet can use either of them to distinguish the markers.for eg give id_red for all the red colored markers ,id_yellow for all the yellow colored markers

```
if(marker.getTitle().toString().equals(id_red )){
        its a red colored marker
 }else{

 }
```

**Or**

You can use snippet for the same thing

```
 if (marker.getSnippet().contains("id_red")) {
     red
    } else{
    // Click of another colored marker
    }
```